# How do I remove this stray underline that only appears in Edge?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I'm implementing [this](https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/hover-underline-menu.html) design element on my website, which uses the Foundation framework. Everything works great, except in Microsoft Edge and IE, there's a stray mark from the underline visible when there isn't supposed to be (i.e. when not interacting with the link).

Here's the code re-created in Codepen:

https://codepen.io/andk/pen/JwrVMg

```css
.hover-underline-menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.hover-underline-menu ul {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu {
  background-color: #2C3840;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a {
  position: relative;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 0.125rem);
  border-bottom: 0.125rem solid white;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a:hover::after {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="hover-underline-menu">
  <ul class="menu align-center">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Notice the dot below the word "One." How can I fix this for Edge/IE? Also, any idea why it only appears on "One" instead of the other nav links?

Thank you!

Comment: increase slightly the percentage by using 51% for example

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good idea! That seemed to work.

Comment: If possible, I would still like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: as you can see, it only happen on IE/Edge so there is nothing to understand, it's a glitch/bug ... using more than 51% will remove the bug

Comment: @TemaniAfif Fair enough! Would you like to submit that as an answer and I'll mark it as solved?

Comment: it's done, I also added another way to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the percentage more than `50%` to be sure the width will be 0 and you will avoid this bug

```css
.hover-underline-menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.hover-underline-menu ul {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu {
  background-color: #2C3840;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a {
  position: relative;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 0.125rem);
  border-bottom: 0.125rem solid white;
  left: 51%;
  right: 51%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a:hover::after {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="hover-underline-menu">
  <ul class="menu align-center">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You can also simplify your code like below without the need of a pseudo element:

```css
.hover-underline-menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.hover-underline-menu ul {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu {
  background-color: #2C3840;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background:
    linear-gradient(white,white) bottom no-repeat;
  background-size:0% 0.125rem;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.hover-underline-menu .menu a:hover {
 background-size:100% 0.125rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="hover-underline-menu">
  <ul class="menu align-center">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, I especially like the second solution that doesn't involve a pseudo element.

Answer (score -1):

In the code below I have added the width properties to the normal state and after states i.e 'width: 0;' and 'width:100%'.  I have also used 'ease-in-out' instead of 'ease' and used display properties 'block' and 'inline-block'.

I have also tested in EDGE and it works

It is the width settings in '::after' and ':hover::after', which make the desired alteration with the former set to zero and later 100%.

See my annotations below for amenments

```css
.hover-underline-menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.hover-underline-menu ul {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu {
  background-color: #2C3840;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; /*added inline-block here */
}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 0.125rem);
  display: block; /* Added display block */
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  width: 0; /* added width property so no dot in EDGE */
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; /* Used ease-in-out instead of ease */
  border-bottom: 0.125rem solid white;

}

.hover-underline-menu .menu a:hover::after {
  
  width: 100%; /* Added width 100% */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="hover-underline-menu">
  <ul class="menu align-center">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: In the above I have simply moved the css line that says: border-bottom: 0.125rem solid white;

Comment: If you have additions, corrections etc, then it is best to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53973793/edit) the answer instead of adding a comment.

Comment: Moving border-bottom causes the line to abruptly disappear when you move the cursor instead of shrinking back down and disappearing gradually, which is not ideal.

Comment: I see @Andrew , I have amended my code so that it now works for EDGE and has the transition in and out - I have also moved the border bottom back and added width properties instead and display inline-block to the none to the normal state and display block to the after state. I will ammend my answer as per Peter B –

Comment: Thanks @ColinGell this answer is also correct and helpful. Adding a width value seems like a great way to solve it.